# Looking for good headset for gaming/youtube/movies

Tags: headphones, headset

My 5th pair of Apple Earbuds broke about a week ago and I'm done. (RIP 2012-2015). I'm looking for a good pair of headphones that will last me long. I'm not going to buy another pair of Earbuds, because I DID, and those were an even bigger pain in the butt.

*MUST-HAVES*:
1. **PC and iPod4** I will be using both devices frequently and a pair of headphones without this support will not be considered.
2. **Microphone.** I am sick of using my iPod4 for skype calls and will need a microphone so I can get better call quality. Please, don't make a recommendation with a separate mike.
3. **Wired.** If it is not possible for the mobile devices to support one cable, then split microphone and audio are fine.
4. **Warranty.** This must come with AT LEAST a 30-day warranty. 1 YR would be ideal, but it think it may be far-fetched.
5. **Color.** Must be black with blue or black with red. I will allow black-with-X combos.
6. **Under $45.** The black Friday sales are coming soon so I expect these not to be that costly. The lower the better. If the headset only has the MUST-HAVES, then it should be under $35. However, don't cheap out; try to find a good model with ALL or most of the optional (but wanted) features.

*ADDITONALLY:*

1. **LED LIGHTS.** They don't have to be customizable, but that would be great.
2. **CONTROLLER.** A controller on the wire would be great fully appreciated. Should have `mute mike`,`mute audio`, and `louder` and `lower`. Mute mick is optional, rest must be if there is a controller.

Comment: Are you willing to budge on the budget? $30 for a headset will give you both bad speakers and a bad microphone, but if you moved the maximum to $50, you could get something halfway decent.

Comment: @Firepower0701 Black Friday is coming up soon and therefore I will except answer that will be on sale for black Friday. I will move the budget up to  $45; but please keep in mind that the mic is for skype calls. Therefore; it does not have to sound like a beast, just provide clear audio output and have noise-canceling because the house can get really busy.

Answer (score 1):

The best bud earphones I've ever used where those which came with the Nokia N8. The satisfy all of your primary requirements, except #4 (the warranty). However, I would imagine that you could pick some up second hand, quite cheaply, and so the warranty would not really be an issue.

[image: Nokia N8 earphones]

As you can see from the photo, they will even satisfy your second optional requirement, as the controller is most useful. No LEDs though, I'm afraid.

The sound was excellent, they were hard wearing and rugged, and the volume control worked with my iPhone 5. I have gone through *so* many flimsy iPhone earbuds that I no longer even bother thinking about them.

I'm sure that you could find some on eBay at a most reasonable price.

The only down side is that if the connections in the jack go bust, they are a little bit hard to fix, but that applies to most bud earphones these days. Gone are the days of easily fixable 1/4" jacks.

As a side note, I ended up losing mine in a Bangkok nightclub, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not come right as yet see if you can find yourself a pair of Steelseries Siberia Raw Prism's.
They are a good price to performance headset and are also extremely comfortable, the only thing I do not like about them is they are plastic but I doubt you will be able to find a set as good as them for that price and if you look after them the plastic is strong enough to last. I see they go for $49 on Amazon at the moment.

[http://www.amazon.com/SteelSeries-Siberia-Prism-Gaming-Headset/dp/B00O06ZN3O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O06ZN3O)

Comment: Can you edit your answer to break down the requirements in the question one by one? It makes it easier for everyone to see how it stacks up against the other answers' recommendations.

Comment: As @Cfinley has asked, please edit this answer to make it clear how this hardware solves the problem. At the moment, this answer falls a little short of the quality standards.

Answer (score 0):

I used to be a fan of Bose until a friend told me about Sennheiser.  They started out making monitors (headphones) for the music industry geared toward musicians and then branched out.

I have these exact headphones and they sound phenomenal and they fit perfectly. [image]  ([Sennheiser CX200.](http://amzn.to/1Sc6rrB) )

Not only does it fit all your specifications, [but it has a huge 2 year warranty](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61L6mtKXPeS.pdf) (one of the reasons I forgot how to spell Bose).